# Using tensorflow to identify lego bricks?

Tags: tensorflow, lego-mindstorms

having read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/how-a-japanese-cucumber-farmer-is-using-deep-learning-and-tensorflow) about a guy who uses tensorflow to sort cucumber into nine different classes I was wondering if this type of process could be applied to a large number of classes. My idea would be to use it to identify Lego parts.

At the moment, a site like Bricklink describes more than [40,000 different parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catLike=W) so it would be a bit different than the cucumber example but I am wondering if it sounds suitable. There is no easy way to get hundreds of pictures for each part but does the following process sound feasible :

- take pictures of a part ;
- try to identify the part using tensorflow ;
- if it does not identify the correct part, take more pictures and feed the neural network with them ;
- go on with the next part.

That way, each time we encounter a new piece we "teach" the network its reference so that it can better be recognized the next time. Like that and after hundreds of iterations monitored by a human, could we imagine tensorflow to be able to recognize the parts? At least the most common ones?

My question might sound stupid but I am not into neural networks so any advice is welcome. At the moment I have not found any way to identify a lego part based on pictures and this "cucumber example" sounds promising so I am looking for some feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that you have 3d cad models of all the parts, which at the very least you could use to produce training images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about the work of Jacques Mattheij, he actually uses a customized version of Xception<sup>1</sup> running on https://keras.io/.

The introduction is [Sorting 2 Metric Tons of Lego](https://jacquesmattheij.com/sorting-two-metric-tons-of-lego).

In [Sorting 2 Tons of Lego, The software Side](https://jacquesmattheij.com/sorting-lego-the-software-side) you can read:

> The hard challenge to deal with next was to get a training set large
>   enough to make working with 1000+ classes possible. At first this
>   seemed like an insurmountable problem. I could not figure out how to
>   make enough images and to label them by hand in acceptable time, even
>   the most optimistic calculations had me working for 6 months or longer
>   full-time in order to make a data set that would allow the machine to
>   work with many classes of parts rather than just a couple.
>
> In the end the solution was staring me in the face for at least a week
>   before I finally clued in: it doesn’t matter. All that matters is that
>   the machine labels its own images most of the time and then all I need
>   to do is correct its mistakes. As it gets better there will be fewer
>   mistakes. This very rapidly expanded the number of training images.
>   The first day I managed to hand-label about 500 parts. The next day
>   the machine added 2000 more, with about half of those labeled wrong.
>   The resulting 2500 parts where the basis for the next round of
>   training 3 days later, which resulted in 4000 more parts, 90% of which
>   were labeled right! So I only had to correct some 400 parts, rinse,
>   repeat… So, by the end of two weeks there was a dataset of 20K images,
>   all labeled correctly.
>
> This is far from enough, some classes are severely under-represented
>   so I need to increase the number of images for those, perhaps I’ll
>   just run a single batch consisting of nothing but those parts through
>   the machine. No need for corrections, they’ll all be labeled
>   identically.

A recent update is [Sorting 2 Tons of Lego, Many Questions, Results](https://jacquesmattheij.com/sorting-lego-many-questions-and-this-is-what-the-result-looks-like).

---

<sup>1</sup>[CHOLLET, François. Xception: Deep Learning with Depthwise Separable Convolutions. *arXiv preprint arXiv:1610.02357*, 2016.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02357)

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I had missed this blog post, he seems to say that the solution was really more efficient than Tensorflow, so I will accept this answer as it seems the best way to go! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have started this using IBM Watson's Visual Recognition.
I had six different bricks to be recognized on the transport belt background.

I am actually thinking about tensorflow, since I can have it running locally.

The codelab : TensorFlow for Poets, describes almost exactly what you want to achieve,

For a demo of the Watson version:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ibmandgoogle/entry/Lego_bricks_recognition_with_Watosn_lego_and_raspberry_pi?lang=en